# error in mysql insert query in MYSQL 5.6.12

Tags: php, mysql

I tried to use the following code to insert,

```
$op=$_POST["ans"];
$username=$_GET["username"];

mysql_query("insert into $username values('Q3','$op')")
or die(mysql_error());
```

But I got the following error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near **'values('Q1','Wrong')'** at line 1

Why am I getting this error? How can I fix it?

Comment: Please, before you write **any** more SQL interfacing code, you must read up on [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) to avoid severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Also, `mysql_query` should not be used in new applications. It's a deprecated interface that's being removed from future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and will make your database code easier to get right.

Comment: `$username` is probably coming out blank, producing `insert into values (...)`. Given your utter lack of **ANY** validation of the POST/GET values and the gaping wide-open SQL injection attack vulnerabilities, I suggest you stop working on this code until you've learned how to produce safe/secure code.

Comment: $username is your suggested table name, while it is for sure a colomn name. Use PDO and follow the admission of tadman.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query structure is not making any sense. You're inserting into `$username`? That's not the name of the table, is it?

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `tablename` values('Q3','" . mysql_real_escape_string($op) . "')") or die(mysql_error());
```

Always be very careful to escape any and all user data being put into your queries, and please, please stop using `mysql_query` in new code.

Comment: ya $username is the name of the table.                                        and i am getting this $username from some other php file.

Comment: Why is `$username` the name of the table? Does each user have their own results in a separate table? That goes against pretty much every database design convention I can think of.

Comment: i am conducting a online test. so i am trying to store all selected options from particular user in his name.                               [link](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/28033818?noredirect=1) for code.

Comment: You should have a `users` table, and then reference that in an `answers` table as a `user_id` column. One table per user is not going to work out in the long run, you could end up with thousands of tables and you'll find it impossible to aggregate data across all of them.

Comment: If you followed convention and created [properly normalized data structures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) and used an ORM like [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) or [Propel](http://propelorm.org/) you would probably avoid most of these problems. Create your user record, then use the ID of that record as a reference in all your related tables.

Comment: Right, but your database structure is still highly unconventional. I'd strongly suggest using one that's properly normalized.

Comment: this one [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18975175/i-am-writing-code-to-conduct-online-test-got-trouble-in-auto-submit/18975523?noredirect=1#18975523)

Comment: I'm just re-iterating what everyone else has already said. Make **one** table for answers.